# RLMArray does not support fast enumeration NSFastEnumerationIterator?

Tags: ios, realm

What's the best way to enforce RLMArray can support NSFastEnumerationIterator？

```
internal override func buildEntryFromResultObject(_ object: RLMObject, x: Double) -> ChartDataEntry
{
    let value = object[_yValueField!]
    let entry: BarChartDataEntry

    if value is RLMArray<AnyObject>
    {
        var values = [Double]()
        var iterator = NSFastEnumerationIterator(value as! RLMArray)
        while let val = iterator.next()
        {
            values.append((val as! RLMObject)[_stackValueField!] as! Double)
        }
        entry = BarChartDataEntry(x: _xValueField == nil ? x : object[_xValueField!] as! Double, yValues: values)
    }
    else
    {
        entry = BarChartDataEntry(x: _xValueField == nil ? x : object[_xValueField!] as! Double, y: value as! Double)
    }

    return entry
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you're more interested in how to make `RLMArray` iterable in Swift, rather than specifically using it with `NSFastEnumerationIterator`.

[Realm's documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#rlmsupport-swift) has this to say:

> We recommend you compile the [Swift/RLMSupport.swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift) file (which is also available in our release zip). This file adds `Sequence` conformance to Realm Objective‑C collection types and re-exposes Objective‑C methods that aren’t natively accessible from Swift like methods including variadic arguments.
>
> Realm Objective‑C doesn’t include this file by default, because that would force all users of Realm Objective‑C to include the hefty Swift dynamic libraries regardless of whether or not they use Swift in their app!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. We are using Swift anyway, so RealmSwift is included. Then we don't need to add RLMSupport.swift addtionally, it is bundled with RealmSwift, right?

Comment: RLMSupport.swift is not a part of Realm Swift, since its purpose is to make using the Realm Objective-C API from Swift more natural that’s not relevant if you’re using only Realm Swift.